# How do I get a refreshToken with adonisJS v5?

Tags: adonis.js

In versions prior to 5, it used:
`await auth.withRefreshToken().generate(user)`

Is there something I can do similar in adonisJS version 5?

Answer (score 0):

no there is not, there is no jwt authentication in adonisjs v5 however I came across this issue and implemented the jwt authentication myself, it's not that hard you will install jsonwebtoken and @types/jsonwebtoken and create a middleware and handle the authentication tokens yourself and that's what the maintainers suggest. if you want jwt authentication you can implement it the same as you would in any nodejs backend framework.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this adonis package that adds JWT authentication to Adonisjs v5 https://github.com/maxgalbu/adonis5-jwt